# Bind a list of the same type viewModels to a tabcontrol in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-controls, caliburn.micro

I'm having trouble binding a list of ViewModels as items to a tab control.

```
//ShellViewModel.cs
private BindableCollection<RecentUnitViewModel> RecentUnitModels { get; set; }
```

```
<!-- ShellView.xaml -->
<GroupBox FontSize="16" Margin="10" FontWeight="DemiBold" Grid.Row="3">
    <GroupBox.Header>Last Seen</GroupBox.Header>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecentUnitModels}" >
    </TabControl>
</GroupBox>
```

Unexpected result: Displays the type "RecentUnitViewModel" instead of the View.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Getting an unexpected result at runtime? Perhaps you could edit your question to include more details about your project.

Comment: If you have not already you should read the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: I just didn't know how to bind to a list of ViewModels with Caliburn.

Comment: It's automatic when you use `x:Name="RecentUnitModels"` instead of ItemsSource

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Caliburn binding for a TabControl is easiest if you have a [Conductor](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) that you bind by convention (set the DataContext to the Conductor instance and name the TabControl "Items".)  The issue here is that a TabControl instantiates a single content presenter that is shared by all tabs, but you need to somehow tell Caliburn.Micro to find the View for the ViewModel when it changes the content.  I found that this works nicely:

```
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

I've made the assumption here that the ViewModels you're binding are true ViewModels (not UserControls) and that you have separate Views (UserControls) that Caliburn.Micro is binding for you.

Comment: That was my problem--learning both Caliburn and WPF at the same time seems to be a bit challenging for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Moyler, WPF definitely has a pretty steep learning curve.  Caliburn is easier if you're willing to use its default conventions.  If you follow the conventions, everything works automagically.  Just be sure the maintenance engineer who inherits your project is trained that changing or removing an 'unused' `x:Name` can cause disastrous effects.

Answer (score 1):

You property needs to be public...

Comment: My mistake, I changed it from being a field to a property and forgot to change the modifier, thanks.